# USB HID device detection

Tags: usb, dbus, hid, udev, hal

I am trying to access an USB HID device under Ubuntu(kernel-3.0). I want to write a program which could notify me whenever an USB device is attached to the bus i.e is there any event generated whenever an USB device is plugged in which I can monitor. I have looked into DBus and HAL without any success. But I don't want linux to load its current modules(USBHID and HID) when the device is plugged in. I also want to ask if the mentioned modules are also the device drivers used for HID devices.

My sole purpose is to run a script whenever an USB device is plugged into the bus which will indirectly call the above mentioned modules.

I am writing my code in C. I am quite new to linux. So it would be of great help if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

The UDisks deamon will send the D-Bus signal "DeviceAdded" when a USB drive is inserted, and probably another "DeviceAdded" for each partition on the drive. If you have automount you would also get a "DeviceChanged" signal when the partition(s) are mounted. You can then query the UDisks interface, as well as individual devices about their properties, for example. You can find more info on the UDisks interface here: http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/udisks/UDisks.html

One way to get more familiar with what goes on with block devices (or whatever) on D-Bus, is to install and use D-Feet to inspect the bus. UDisks appear on the System bus. You can see what is there and inspect the properties for individual devices as well as the UDisks interface itself.

Another way, which would also allow you to see what signals are transmitted on the bus, is to run dbus-monitor from the command line.

Comment: I wrote a program (similar to http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/udev_example.c)which used libudev monitor to look for HID device addition events. It looked for hidraw entries under /dev which appeared only after the device was enumerated. So I thought I had no option except for writing a kernel driver. Thanks for the link..

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped in some way at least.

Comment: The answer somewhat missed the point. The OP asked for event generated for the plug/unplug of USB Human Interaction Device (HID), not a USB storage device. Apparently we have to monitor udev directly like what's done in the C program listed by @pattu777.